# Can I use Fourier transform of Matsubara Green's functions for imaginary time-ordered polarizability function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fourier-transform, greens-functions, many-body

I am learning Matsubara Green's functions using Henrik Bruus, Karsten Flensberg, *Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics, An Introduction* (2016). There, the authors calculated the Matsubara polarizability function of *non-interacting* electrons from Eq. (11.86)

$$
\chi_0(\textbf{q},\tau)= \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}\sigma}G_0(\textbf{k+q}\sigma,\tau)G_0(\textbf{k}\sigma,-\tau)
$$

to Eq. (11.87)

$$
\chi_0(\textbf{q},iq_n) = \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{ik_n} \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}\sigma}\mathcal{G}_0(\textbf{k+q}\sigma,ik_n + iq_n)\mathcal{G}_0(\textbf{k}\sigma,ik_n)
$$

using Matsubara sums. And eventually the result is in Eq. (11.88)

$$
\chi_0(\textbf{q},iq_n) = \frac{1}{V}\sum_{\textbf{k}\sigma}\frac{n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}})-n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})}{iq_n +\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}} - \varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}}}
$$

But I thought I could directly use the Fourier transform in Eq. (11.28)

$$\mathcal{C} = \int_0^\beta e^{i\omega_n \tau} \mathcal{C}(\tau)d\tau$$

in order to get $\chi_0(\textbf{q},i\omega_n)$. I first obtained

$$
G_0(\textbf{k+q}\sigma,\tau) = e^{-\tau\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}}}(n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})-1),  G_0(\textbf{k}\sigma,-\tau) = e^{\tau\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}}}n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}})
$$

Then,

$$
\chi_0(\textbf{q},\tau) = \frac{1}{V} \sum_{\textbf{k}\sigma} e^{\tau(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}}-\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})}n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}})(n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})-1)
$$

and its Fourier transform is

$$
\chi_0(\textbf{q},i\omega_n) = \frac{1}{V}\sum_{\textbf{k}\sigma}n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}})(n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})-1)\int_0^\beta e^{(i\omega_n + \varepsilon_{\textbf{k}} - \varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})\tau} d\tau
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{V}\sum_{\textbf{k}\sigma}\frac{n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}})(n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})-1)[e^{i \beta \omega_n} e^{\beta(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}} - \varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})} - 1]}{i\omega_n +\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}} - \varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}}} 
$$

But no matter if $e^{i \beta \omega_n}=1$ or $e^{i \beta \omega_n}=-1$, the numerator (i.e., the $n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}})(n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})-1)(\pm e^{\beta(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}} - \varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}})} - 1)$) is never $(n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k}})-n_F(\varepsilon_{\textbf{k+q}}))$ (I verified this using Mathematica).

Is there a reason why we cannot directly use the integral form of Matsubara Fourier transform (i.e., Eq. (11.28) on Bruus & Flensberg), or is it that we are able to do so but I just made a mathmatical mistake somewhere?